# Sum of city using group by country in sparql query

Tags: sparql, semantics

I want to calculate the total number of cities per country using a SPARQL query in Protege tool.  The relation between city and country is that city `isLocatedIn` country. I tried this query that are given below but it fails.  So kindly help me.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
 PREFIX ge:<http://www.semanticweb.org/waqas/ontologies/2016/4/untitled-ontology-15#>
SELECT  ( ?country SUM(?city) AS  ?TotalCity )
    WHERE {  ?city ge:isLocatedIn ?country . ?city rdf:type ?city} 
    GROUP BY(?country)
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify how it fails.  Is the count wrong?  Does it return no results?  Is there an error message?  The more specifics, the more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a simple syntax issue.  See [Grouping and Aggregation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#convertGroupAggSelectExpressions) in the SPARQL 1.1 spec:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ge:<http://www.semanticweb.org/waqas/ontologies/2016/4/untitled-ontology-15#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?city) AS ?TotalCity)
WHERE {  
   ?city ge:isLocatedIn ?country . 
   ?city rdf:type ge:City .
} 
GROUP BY(?country)
```

Comment: According to your query the output is,only show 1 row with data country column is empty and city column show this output "0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#integer>

Comment: No way I could comment on that without knowing something about the data.  The query should be correct, provided you have triples such as `<Madrid> ge:isLocatedIn <Spain>`.

Answer (score -2):

Answer of my question

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX ge:<http://www.semanticweb.org/waqas/ontologies/2016/4/untitled-ontology-15#>
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?city) AS  ?TotalCity)
WHERE {  
   ?city ge:isLocatedIn ?country . 
   ?city rdf:type ge:City .
} 
GROUP BY(?country)
```

Comment: You should explain what the reason was, i.e. a syntax issue AND that you wrongly used the triple pattern `?city rdf:type ?city` (which is obviously wrong) instead of `?city rdf:type ge:City` .

Comment: ?city is a  variable and ge:City is a class